# Can TortoiseSVN (or SVN) do batch diff like Mercurial?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisesvn

I use Mercurial and TortoiseSVN, and with Mercurial, I can use

```
hg vdiff
```

and then kdiff3 will come out saying there are 5 files that got modified in the project tree, and then I can go to menu bar to "Expand Directories" and see the files that have diffs, and click on each of them.

To my surprise, TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to have this function.  When I look at the project folder, and right click for TortoiseSVN, the usual "Diff" action is missing from the menu bar.  Is there a way to make it work like `hg vdiff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action in the TortoiseSVN menu is called "SVN Check for modifications".

Comment: both M4N's method and Albin's method work but this one is closer to the original purpose.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the commit dialog (by selecting Commit in the context menu) to get a list of all files which were modified locally. Then, by double-clicking a file you can see the changes made in that file.